# Conan.io and netbeans - howto setup a project

Tags: netbeans, conan

I'm trying NetBeans as my new IDE for c++. I would love to use conan.io as package manager.

My conanfile.py looks like this (from the conan site):

```
class MyConanTestProj(ConanFile):
    settings = "os", "compiler", "build_type", "arch"
    requires = "Protobuf/3.1.0@inexorgame/stable", "Boost/1.64.0@conan/stable" # comma separated list of requirements
    generators = "cmake", "txt"
    default_options = "Poco:shared=True", "OpenSSL:shared=True", "Boost:shared=True"

    def imports(self):
      self.copy("*.dll", dst="bin", src="bin") # From bin to bin
      self.copy("*.dylib*", dst="bin", src="lib") # From lib to bin
#      self.copy('*.so*', dst='bin', src='lib')

    def build(self):
      cmake = CMake(self)
      cmake.configure()
      cmake.build()
```

My CMakeLists.txt:

```
project(MyTestProj)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.12)

add_definitions("-std=c++14")

include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
conan_basic_setup()

add_executable(testProj testProj.cpp)
target_link_libraries(testProj ${CONAN_LIBS})
```

testProj.cpp: (just to see it compile and link...)

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
int main(void) { return 0; }
```

When I create a build dir and run conan install and so on it works:

```
mkdir build -p && cd build && conan install .. && cmake .. -G "Unix Makefiles" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release && cmake --build
```

But in NetBeans it shows me an unresolved include (netbeans has no idea there conan has stored the boost files).

How to configurate netbeans to use the include paths generated by conan?
Conan created conanbildinfo.cmake and conanbuildinfo.txt with the full paths included but i don't know how to use them in netbeans.

Hope someone could tell me how to setup this correctly (or give me a short example project for netbeans) - Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans might be using a particular build folder layout, as previous versions of CLion did in the past, just putting the "temporary" build folders somewhere in the system.

I guess that the CMake execution is complaining about not finding the `conanbuildinfo.cmake` file, not the Boost headers.

So, the first thing is to know which folder is being used by Netbeans as CMake binary dir. You could add to your `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
if(NOT EXISTS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake) 
    message(FATAL_ERROR "Missing conanbuildinfo. Move to ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR} folder, and run conan install there")
endif()

include(${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/conanbuildinfo.cmake)
conan_basic_setup()
```

Then, just `cd` to that folder, `conan install` with the respective configuration (note that this process may need to be run for different configurations, like Debug/Release).